# Does Sweeping Wind activate Resolve?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The monk passive Resolve states that "Damage you deal reduces enemy damage by 25% for 2.5 seconds."

Does Sweeping Wind activate this effect?

I've been taking Seize the Initiative over Resolve due to its 100% uptime, but since I have an 80% sweeping wind uptime, and it hits all the mobs around me, Resolve could really help out (except against very long ranged mobs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will, since the vortex qualifies as your damage as opposed to a summons like a WD dog.

Comment: So my Mystic ally won't activate it?